# Style buttons with different palette colors

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

**Using Material-UI v1:**

I want to create multiple buttons with different colors, which will be taken from the Material-UI palette.

Ideally, I would love to have something like:

```
<Button color="colorFromThePalette">
<Button color={ theme.palette.myColor }>
```

But I get the following error:

> Failed prop type: Invalid prop `color` of value `someValue` supplied to `Button`, expected one of ["default","inherit","primary","accent","contrast"].

What are my options, considering I want  to be consistent with the material design palette?

Comment: Take a look at the [Customization section](https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/customization/themes/#configuration-variables). You can override the default values with your own but in the end, you will still have to use the defined color keywords.

Comment: I have more than 4-5 colors I would like to use, so overriding "primary"/"accent" colors in my theme is not a good option for me.

Comment: Your option then is to add a `className` to each button with custom CSS classes that define the background-color you want to use. When importing this style sheet, make sure to import it after importing the material-ui parts.

Comment: But overriding the css background isn't enough - I've already tried it. It gets messy when you click on the button and the background changed to a whole other.

Comment: That is more or less expected since this framework is not intended to be used like this. With CSS override you have to understand how it boils down to the rendered HTML and adjust your stylesheet to that. You will also have to cover the hover, focus, active and other possible states. In other words it's like reengineering the framework. I'm using a different library, `reactstrap`, and I managed like this in the end.

Comment: Will try that, thanks. It's just doesn't make much sense to block that feature..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155853/discussion-between-matei-radu-and-galah92).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **classes** property and override only desired keys. For me **flatPrimary** and **raisedPrimary** was enough.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import { fade } from 'material-ui/styles/colorManipulator';
import teal from 'material-ui/colors/teal';
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';

const styles = theme => ({
  flatTeal: {
    color: teal[500],
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: fade(teal[500], 0.12)
    }
  },
  raisedTeal: {
    backgroundColor: teal[500],
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: teal[700],
      '@media (hover: none)': {
        backgroundColor: teal[500]
      }
    }
  }
});

const Teal = props => {
  const { classes } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      <Button color="primary">
        Primary flat
      </Button>
      <Button raised color="primary">
        Primary raised
      </Button>
      <Button
        color="primary"
        classes={{ flatPrimary: classes.flatTeal }}
      >
        Teal flat
      </Button>
      <Button
        raised
        color="primary"
        classes={{ raisedPrimary: classes.raisedTeal }}
      >
        Teal raised
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};

Teal.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(Teal);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/v8r33xnlr5

Comment: Could you provide the code itself in a [mcve] in case the link becomes unavailable?